# Publishing a google script on a custom domain

Tags: google-apps-script, web-deployment

Using Google Apps Script. I know it is not a programming issue, but got no better idea who to turn to.

- GoDaddy is the provider
- Script is deployed as web app
- Mapping is done and works with HTML
  **...but doesn't work with Google Script.**

The HTML page was only created for clarification.

How should this be resolved?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not possible, see issue 546
http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=546

Probably the best you can do now (besides staring the issue) is to make an alias/webhop to your apps script link.